# Error while packaging Unreal project for VR (APK): "AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #10: Unexpected error during link"

Tags: gradle, unreal-engine4, aapt

I am trying to package and Unreal Project for VR (APK). I have search guides and forums, but haven't been able to find a solution to this error:

```
ProcessResult.StdOut:   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
ProcessResult.StdOut:   
ProcessResult.StdOut:   * What went wrong:
ProcessResult.StdOut:   Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
ProcessResult.StdOut:   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
ProcessResult.StdOut:      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #10: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
ProcessResult.StdOut:        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
ProcessResult.StdOut:   
ProcessResult.StdOut:   * Try:
ProcessResult.StdOut:   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
ProcessResult.StdOut:   
ProcessResult.StdOut:   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
ProcessResult.StdOut:   
ProcessResult.StdOut:   BUILD FAILED in 8s
ProcessResult.StdOut:   > Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
ProcessResult.StdOut:   23 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 22 up-to-date
ProcessResult.StdOut:   ERROR: cmd.exe failed with args /c "C:\repos\ICDCorePlugin\Intermediate\Android\arm64\gradle\rungradle.bat" :app:assembleDebug
CommandUtils.Run: Took 10.4127733s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=6
Program.Main: UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (C:\Users\jpearl\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.26\UBT-ICD_Core_Project-Android-Development.txt)
Program.Main: AutomationException: UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (C:\Users\jpearl\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.26\UBT-ICD_Core_Project-Android-Development.txt)
Program.Main:    at AutomationTool.CommandUtils.RunUBT(CommandEnvironment Env, String UBTExecutable, String CommandLine) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\UBTUtils.cs:line 52
Program.Main:    at AutomationTool.CommandUtils.RunUBT(CommandEnvironment Env, String UBTExecutable, FileReference Project, String Target, UnrealTargetPlatform Platform, UnrealTargetConfiguration Config, String AdditionalArgs) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\UBTUtils.cs:line 89
Program.Main:    at AutomationTool.UE4Build.BuildWithUBT(String TargetName, UnrealTargetPlatform TargetPlatform, UnrealTargetConfiguration Config, FileReference UprojectPath, Boolean ForceFlushMac, Boolean DisableXGE, String InAddArgs) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\UE4Build.cs:line 235
Program.Main:    at AutomationTool.UE4Build.Build(BuildAgenda Agenda, Nullable`1 InDeleteBuildProducts, Boolean InUpdateVersionFiles, Boolean InForceNoXGE, Boolean InUseParallelExecutor, Boolean InShowProgress, Nullable`1 InChangelistNumberOverride, Dictionary`2 InTargetToManifest) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\UE4Build.cs:line 1111
Program.Main:    at Project.Build(BuildCommand Command, ProjectParams Params, Int32 WorkingCL, ProjectBuildTargets TargetMask) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Scripts\BuildProjectCommand.Automation.cs:line 215
Program.Main:    at BuildCookRun.DoBuildCookRun(ProjectParams Params) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Scripts\BuildCookRun.Automation.cs:line 205
Program.Main:    at BuildCookRun.ExecuteBuild() in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Scripts\BuildCookRun.Automation.cs:line 39
Program.Main:    at AutomationTool.BuildCommand.Execute() in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\BuildCommand.cs:line 263
Program.Main:    at AutomationTool.Automation.Execute(List`1 CommandsToExecute, Dictionary`2 Commands) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\Automation.cs:line 547
Program.Main:    at AutomationTool.Automation.Process(String[] Arguments, StartupTraceListener StartupListener) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\Automation.cs:line 511
Program.Main:    at AutomationTool.Program.MainProc(String[] Arguments, StartupTraceListener StartupListener) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Program.cs:line 175
Program.Main:    at AutomationTool.Program.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Main>b__2() in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Program.cs:line 87
Program.Main:    at AutomationTool.InternalUtils.RunSingleInstance(Func`1 Main) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\AutomationUtils\Utils.cs:line 737
Program.Main:    at AutomationTool.Program.Main(String[] Arguments) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Program.cs:line 87
Program.Main: AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=6 (6)
```

I have followed the Unreal Engine setup for Android development guide. Reinstalled Android Studio and JDK. Cleared the Gradle cache. Reviewed forums with similar issues.